# Disabling manipulation inertia in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

The Windows 8 manipulation events apply inertia by default, [as described in this article](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2012/02/Windows-8-Touch-Events-Interactions.html), i.e. manipulation delta events keep firing after the user has lifted their finger.

Does anyone know how to 'tune' or disable this inertia? I have tried handling `ManipulationInertiaStarting` and setting `e.Handled=true`, but this does not disable inertia.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set these up using the [ManipulationMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.manipulationmode), eg.

```
dragOverlay.ManipulationMode =
    ManipulationModes.TranslateInertia |
    ManipulationModes.TranslateX |
    ManipulationModes.TranslateY;
```

vs.

```
dragOverlay.ManipulationMode =
    ManipulationModes.TranslateX |
    ManipulationModes.TranslateY;
```

You can also check e.IsInertial in the manipulation events and call [e.Complete()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.manipulationdeltaroutedeventargs.complete%28v=win.10%29.aspx) to stop the current manipulation without inertia.